# VSCode: How to set env variable for VSC runtime?

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code, environment-variables

I'm wondering if it's possible to set environment variables for the VSC Runtime as a whole *without launching from terminal*?

As a simple example, if I want to set `all_proxy=""` for every extension that runs with VSCode (i.e. the Docker extension), the only way I know right now to accomplish this is:

1. Go to my terminal (e.g. iTerm or Hyper)
2. Set the environment variable, i.e. `export all_proxy=""`
3. Run code from the terminal, e.g. `code /path/to/project-workdir`.

Is there a way to get VSCode to load with these environment variables configured, but done on a project-specific basis without needing me to first manually set them in the terminal?

Yes, I am aware that I can set up terminal-based automation to automatically set environment variables when in a directory, but I'm wondering if this is possible for VSCode without resorting to terminal trickery?

Comment: I've answered this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75771298/11107541

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you mean this?

`terminal.integrated.env.linux`

[image]

Comment: Almost, but I was looking for something vscode-wide, such that even the Docker extension would recognize it. I have yet to try what you suggested, but I suspect it'll only affect the terminal; happy to be proven wrong though!

Comment: Vadim, Thank you so mach for your solution

Comment: indeed, this answer is wrong. It will only affect shells in integrated terminals of VS Code- not the VS Code process itself. cc @ericmjl I suggest you unaccept this answer.