# How can I specify environment variables for the VS Code process in my VS Code settings?

Tags: visual-studio-code, environment-variables

I find those two method to add environment variables.

1. add environment variables in `terminal.integrated.env.osx` for terminal。
2. add environment variables in `launch.json` for debugging.

But no similar config options for VSCode Process。

Some plugins often need to access specific environmental variables. In this case, I can only set up an environment variables in Terminal.App, and then open through the code command.

I hope to add this environment variable in the VS Code setting file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of existing VS Code settings that allow you to do this. I'm not surprised, since in general, you can't change the environment of a process that has already been started. See the following on unix.stackexchange.com for more info: [change environment of a running process](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/38205/550426).

I suppose this could technically be implemented: VS Code could change its executable into a wrapper program which reads [the VS Code settings file(s)](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings), then [`exec`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exec_(system_call))s (without `fork`ing) the actual VS Code executable with modified environment variables from the settings. Feel free to [raise a feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=feature_request.md) and see if this is actually a legitimate idea (I'm not sure).

You can specify environment variables to add to the environment of a process when you start that process. See [the `env` command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Env).

Also related if you're using a shell like Bash:

- [Setting an environment variable before a command in Bash is not working for the second command in a pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10856129/11107541)
- [How can I set an environment variable only for the duration of the script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7128542/11107541)
- [How set multiple env variables for a bash command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26189662/11107541)
- [Setting environment variable for one program call in bash using env](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13998075/11107541)

Or, it may be acceptable to you to just modify your system environment, which applies to all processes started in the system by default. Related:

- [Setting environment variables on OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/q/135688/11107541)
- (askubuntu.com) [How do I add environment variables?](https://askubuntu.com/q/58814/1624654)
- for windows: (superuser.com) [What are PATH and other environment variables, and how can I set or use them?](https://superuser.com/q/284342/1749748)

There's a slightly related feature-request about this here for the extension host process: [API: allow an extension to change the environment variables #152806](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/152806). See also [this comment there](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/152806#issuecomment-1165577237) about more broadly applying it to the "root" VS Code process, [this update/summary](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/152806#issuecomment-1208222057), and [this note about using `process.env` for the extension host](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/152806#issuecomment-1306330000).

Comment: If anyone reading this ends up raising an issue ticket like I suggested, please either comment here with the link to the issue ticket, or notify me in the issue ticket with "@starball5" and a link to this Stack Overflow post so I can update it.